# Plotting geojson points in html

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, geojson

I am creating a webmap similar to the example here [example](http://maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro/), but with my data.

My geojson points won't display like the examples, here's what my geojson file **points.geojson** looks like:

```
    {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "RENTAL_ID": 146057249, "CUSTOMER_I": 2256099, "LOCATION": "Boston", "VEHICLE_VI": "FHB 1675", "START_DATE": "2017\/03\/1 00:03:00", "END_DATE_L": "2017\/03\/1 00:10:00", "END_LATITU": 30.22478, "END_LONGIT": -97.72464, "DISTANCE": 5, "DURATION": 7, "DURATION_P": 0, "DURATION_D": 7, "SERVICE_DR": 0, "VEHICLE_TY": "HW 2.0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 42.355672, -71.058712 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "RENTAL_ID": 146057187, "CUSTOMER_I": 2435897, "LOCATION": "Boston", "VEHICLE_VI": "JHD 8492", "START_DATE": "2017\/03\/1 00:00:00", "END_DATE_L": "2017\/03\/1 00:19:00", "END_LATITU": 30.25766855, "END_LONGIT": -97.7383573, "DISTANCE": 13, "DURATION": 19, "DURATION_P": 0, "DURATION_D": 19, "SERVICE_DR": 0, "VEHICLE_TY": "B Class" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 42.361507, -71.090126 ] } }
]
}
```

And here's my code i have written:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #map{ height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

  // initialize the map
    var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.09], 13);

  // load a tile layer
    L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
        attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
        maxZoom: 100,
        minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

  // load GeoJSON from an external file
    $.getJSON("point.geojson",function(data){
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
        L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why are my points not displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your points do appear, but not where you expect them to.

GeoJSON format expects coordinates in the order `[longitude, latitude]`. Leaflet then internally reverses this order, since it uses `[latitude, longitude]`.

But you still need to feed a GeoJSON compliant data.

Comment: thanks for the coordinate explanation, so do you mean by "GeoJSON compliant" data by reversing the coordinates or what?

Comment: THANK YOU! that was the issue and running it through chrome, so I switched the browser to Foxfire and reversed the coordinates, thanks again!