# Mapbox - new L.markers on top of map

Tags: jquery, json, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to plot USGS Earthquake data and am getting a very odd issue.  My query gets all the results and plots the 1st one but the remaining results append on top of the map.

[image]

```
function getEarthquakes(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "data/earthquakes-today.json",
        error: function (err) { console.log(err)},
        success: function (results, status, xhr) {
            jQuery(results.features).each(function(index, i) {
                L.marker([i.geometry.coordinates[0], i.geometry.coordinates[1]]).bindPopup(i.geometry.coordinates[0]+", "+i.geometry.coordinates[1]).addTo(map);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Any idea what would cause this? There are no console log errors and when I console.log the results I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [Plotting geojson points in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878889/plotting-geojson-points-in-html/43882023#43882023), you simply use coordinates in the wrong order.

Given the data that you show, you seem to receive in `results` an array of GeoJSON Features. In that case, you can directly feed it into [`L.geoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson) factory, which will internally reverse the coordinates order for you:

```js
L.geoJSON(results).addTo(map)
```

Otherwise, make sure you reverse them yourself:

```js
//        [latitude                 , longitude]
L.marker(([i.geometry.coordinates[1], i.geometry.coordinates[0]])
```